# Vue: get image width + height returns zero on component load

Tags: vue.js

My component is a modal which displays an `<img>` with some tags on top.
I get the image dimensions using  `const size = this.$refs.media.getBoundingClientRect()`.
However, the height and width is 0, so the tags become placed wrong.

So it seems the image hasn't loaded yet? If I delay getting the height+width with setTimeout, I do get the width and height. But it seems like a not too reliable workaround.

I have "`v-cloak`" on the modal, but that doesn't work.

I can get the html element with this.$refs.media, but it doesn't mean that the image is loaded, apparently. 
So, is there a way to check if the image is loaded? Is there some way to delay the component until the image is loaded?

One more thing: if I add a "width" and "height" in inline style on the img, then those values are available directly. But I don't want to set the size that way because it ruins the responsiveness.

The code doesn't say much more, but it is basically:

```
<modal>
    <vue-draggable-resizable                    // <-- each tag
        v-for="( tag, index ) in tags" 
       :x="convertX(tag.position.x)" 
       :y="convertY(tag.position.y)"
       (other parameters)
```

```
convertX (x) { 
     const size = this.$refs.media.getBoundingClientRect()
     return x * (size.width - 100)                     // <--- 0 width
```

```
async mounted () {

    this.renderTags(this.media.tags)          // <-- needs img width and height
```

**Updated, solution**

As the below answer says, I can use the `onload` event. I also came across the `"@load"` event, which I tried and it worked. I can't find it in the documentation though(?) (I searched for `@load` and `v-on:load`). Using "onload" directly on the image element didn't work though, so `@load` seems to be the way.

If I have a data property:

```
data () {
    return {
       imgLoaded: false
```

I can set it to true with a method using `@load` on the image:

```
<img 
    @load="whenImgLoaded" 


 <template v-if="imgLoaded = true">           
       <vue-draggable-resizable     
            :x="convertX(tag.position.x)" 
            :y="convertY(tag.position.y)"
             (other parameters)

methods: {
    whenImgLoaded(){
         this.imgLoaded = true;
         this.renderTags(this.media.tags)
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the image first via javascript, and after it's loaded run the `renderTags` method.

E.g., do something like this:

```
async mounted() {
    let image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        this.renderTags(this.media.tags)   
    };
    image.src = 'https://some-image.png'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the "onload" was what I needed. While googling I came across the "@load" event which I tried and it worked. So I can mark your answer as accepted since it's the same principle.